# google analytics (401) Login Required error

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

i am using google analytics php api to retrieve my data. on index.php i have authorization process done which works fine and i get successful login on this page i have link to another php page where i want to display all my properties so how i can post my login credentials to properties.php and create an analytics object to retrieve all the webproperties

code index.php look like this

```
session_start();
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';



$scriptUri = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('online'); // default: offline
$client->setApplicationName('XXXX');
$client->setClientId('XXXXXX');
$client->setClientSecret('XXXXX');
$client->setRedirectUri($scriptUri);
$client->setDeveloperKey('XXXXXX'); // API key
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics');


$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) { // logout: destroy token
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    die('Logged out.');
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) { // we received the positive auth callback, get the token and store it in session
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) { // extract token from session and configure client
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) { // auth call to google
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header("Location: ".$authUrl);
    die;
}
TRY{

    }

?>
```

Comment: If you save the refreshtoken and send it to your other page.  You can use that to get a new accesstoken for your query's.

Comment: @LindaL thanks for your reply but please can you give me an example ?? and does any thing have to be change in api console??

Comment: Unfortunately my PHP is very rusty.  But i found this after a bit of googleing.  https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/analytics/demo/authHelper.php  I have a blog post about how Oauth2 works but its in C# but it will explain the difference between Authentication code, access token and refresh token.  http://daimto.com/google-api-and-oath2/